# Covariant derivative in cylindrical coordinates

Tags: differential-geometry

I am confused by the Wolfram article on [cylindrical coordinates](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CylindricalCoordinates.html). Specifically, I do not understand how they go from equation (48) to equations (49)-(57).

Equation (48) shows that the covariant derivative is:

$$A_{j;k} = \frac{1}{g_{kk}}\frac{\partial A_j}{\partial x_k} - \Gamma^i_{jk}A_i$$

The next few equations expand this for the case of cylindrical coordinates, equation (50) is:

$$A_{r;\theta} = \frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial A_r}{\partial \theta} - \frac{A_\theta}{r}$$

The contravariant metric tensor has non-zero elements:

$$g^{11} = 1$$
$$g^{22} = \frac{1}{r^2}$$
$$g^{33} = 1$$

And the Christoffel symbols of the second kind have non-zero elements:

$$\Gamma^1_{22} = -r$$
$$\Gamma^2_{12} = \frac{1}{r}$$
$$\Gamma^2_{21} = \frac{1}{r}$$

If I plug these values back into their definition of the covariant derivative I get for equation (50):

$$A_{r;\theta} = \frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\partial A_r}{\partial \theta} - \frac{A_\theta}{r}$$

Why does this not match up with their results?

Comment: Once again - this comes down to whether $A_j$ are meant to be the holonomic coordinates of $A$ or its orthonormal coordinates.

Comment: @K.defaoite Can you elaborate? I have the same problem as the OP, and I cannot make sense of it. How should one write eq. 48 to ensure that the scale factors (basis vectors) appear. As written, I derive the equation with 1/r^2 as the author does... Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @dpholmes Please have a look at my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Given a vector $\boldsymbol v$ on a manifold, there are an infinite number of ways to represent it as a sum of basis elements. The standard choice in differential geometry is to use the *holonomic* basis, that is, given the coordinate vector $\boldsymbol x=(x^1,\dots ,x^n)$, and some coordinates $q^1,\dots ,q^n$

$$\boldsymbol e_i(\boldsymbol p)= \frac{\partial\boldsymbol x}{\partial q^i}(\boldsymbol p)\tag{1}$$
And **not** the normalized holonomic basis,
$$\hat{\boldsymbol e}_i(\boldsymbol p)=\left\Vert\frac{\partial\boldsymbol x}{\partial q^i}(\boldsymbol p)\right\Vert^{-1}~\frac{\partial\boldsymbol x}{\partial q^i}(\boldsymbol p)\tag{2}$$

For instance, if we are using the standard basis $q^i=x^i$ then $\boldsymbol e_1=(1,\dots,0)$ etc. and in this case all of the unit vectors have a magnitude of unity, so there is no distinction between the normalized and holonomic bases.

But what happens if our coordinate vector is a more complicated function of its coordinates? E.g for 2D polar coordinates,
$$\boldsymbol x=\begin{pmatrix}x^1 \\ x^2\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}q^1\cos(q^2) \\ q^1\sin(q^2)\end{pmatrix}$$

Then there is a distinction, and $\boldsymbol e_i\neq \hat{\boldsymbol e}_i$ in general. Therefore, it makes a difference whether we represent our vector as
$$\boldsymbol v=v^i\boldsymbol e_i\tag{3}$$
Or as
$$\boldsymbol v=\hat{v}^i\hat{\boldsymbol e}_i\tag{4}$$

Using $(1),(2)$, the different bases are related by
$$\hat{\boldsymbol e}_i=\frac{1}{\Vert\boldsymbol e_i\Vert}\boldsymbol e_i$$
Which, using $(3),(4)$ means the normalized and non-normalized components are related by
$$ v^i=\frac{1}{\Vert\boldsymbol e_i\Vert}\hat{v}^i\tag{*}$$

---

So, given a vector $\boldsymbol v$ with its coordinates $v^i$ represented in the **holonomic** basis, the [formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariant_derivative#Covariant_derivative_by_field_type) for its covariant derivative is
$$(\nabla v)^i{}_j=\partial_jv^i+\Gamma^i_{jk}v^k$$
The fact that the formula Wolfram Mathworld gives has that weird factor of $\frac{1}{g_{ii}}$ in front should already tip you off that something funny is going on. Doing some algebra, this gives the $(1,2)$ or $(r,\theta)$ component of the covariant derivative of $\boldsymbol v$ as

$$(\nabla v)^r{}_\theta=\partial_{\theta}v^r-rv^\theta$$
However, if we want to represent our results with the normalized components $\hat{v}^i$, this becomes

$$(\nabla v)^r{}_\theta=\partial_{\theta}\left(\frac{1}{\Vert\boldsymbol e_r\Vert}\hat{v}^r\right)-r~\frac{1}{\Vert\boldsymbol e_\theta\Vert}\hat{v}^\theta$$

Given that the coordinate vector is $\boldsymbol x=(q^1\cos(q^2),q^1\sin(q^2),q^3)=(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta,z)$ you can calculate by yourself that
$$\Vert\boldsymbol e_r\Vert=1~~,~~\Vert\boldsymbol e_\theta\Vert=r$$

Using that result, and $(*)$, we get

$$(\nabla v)^r{}_{\theta}=\partial_\theta \hat{v}^r-\hat{v}^\theta$$
But, hm.... something still isn't right. There appears to be a missing factor of $1/r$. Then we realize - the *tensor* components on the left hand side are still being represented with the holonomic basis! Recall that we can represent a $(1,1)$ tensor as

$$\mathbf T=T^i{}_j~\boldsymbol e_i\otimes \boldsymbol e^j$$
Where $\boldsymbol e^j=g^{jk}\boldsymbol e_k$ is the *dual basis*. Once again we can make a dual *normalized* basis,
$$\hat{\boldsymbol e}^j=\frac{1}{\Vert\boldsymbol e^j\Vert}\boldsymbol e^j$$
So if we represent the tensor $\mathbf T$ with its normalized components,
$$\mathbf T=\hat{T}^i{}_j~\hat{\boldsymbol e}_i\otimes \hat{\boldsymbol e}^j$$
They are related to the holonomic components $T^i{}_j$ via
$$T^i{}_j=\frac{1}{\Vert\boldsymbol e_i\Vert}\frac{1}{\Vert\boldsymbol e^j\Vert}\hat{T}^i{}_j\tag{**}$$

You can compute the dual basis vectors for cylindrical coordinates to be
$$\boldsymbol e^r=\begin{pmatrix}\cos \theta & \sin\theta & 0\end{pmatrix} \\ 
\boldsymbol e^\theta=\frac{1}{r^2}\begin{pmatrix}-r\sin\theta & r\cos\theta & 0\end{pmatrix} \\ \boldsymbol e^z=\begin{pmatrix}0&0&1\end{pmatrix}$$
Hence
$$\Vert\boldsymbol e^\theta\Vert=\frac{1}{r}$$
So using that result, and $(**)$, you get
$$(\nabla v)^{r}{}_\theta=\frac{1}{\Vert\boldsymbol e_r\Vert}\frac{1}{\Vert\boldsymbol e^\theta\Vert}(\widehat{\nabla v})^r{}_\theta=r~(\widehat{\nabla v})^r{}_\theta$$
And hence

$$\boxed{(\widehat{\nabla v})^r{}_\theta=\frac{1}{r}(\nabla v)^{r}{}_\theta=\frac{1}{r}\partial_\theta v^r-\frac{1}{r}v^\theta}$$

The formula that you were looking for.

---

### **MORAL OF THE STORY:**

All of the differential geometry formulas in almost any reputable textbook are given using the holonomic basis. (Why? Because they're generally simpler.) So - **stick to the holonomic basis for as long as you possibly can.** If you *must* convert to the orthonormal basis, do it at the **end**, **after** you have finished all of your calculations. If you do not, you will use formulas that work when the components are expressed in a holonomic basis, on a vector where you have represented the components using a normalized basis, and you are at a **high risk** of getting incorrect results.

---

Reference - Christoffel symbols and covariant derivative components in cylindrical coordinates

Christoffel symbols

$$\Gamma^r_{\theta\theta}=-r \\ \Gamma^{\theta}_{r\theta}=\Gamma^\theta_{\theta r}=\frac{1}{r}\\\text{all others zero}$$

Covariant derivative

$$\nabla\boldsymbol u=\begin{pmatrix}\partial_r u^r & \partial_\theta u^r-ru^\theta & \partial_z u^r \\ \partial_r u^\theta+\frac{1}{r}u^\theta & \partial_\theta u^\theta +\frac{1}{r}u^r & \partial_z u^\theta \\ \partial_r u^z & \partial_\theta u^z & \partial_z u^z\end{pmatrix} \\ \text{(holonomic basis)}$$

$$\nabla \boldsymbol u=\begin{bmatrix}
\partial_ru^r & \frac{1}{r}\left(\partial_\theta u^r-u^\theta\right) & \partial_z u^r \\
\partial_r u^\theta & \frac{1}{r}\left(\partial_\theta u^\theta+u^r\right) & \partial_z u^\theta \\
\partial_r u^z & \frac{1}{r}\partial_\theta u^z & \partial_z u^z
\end{bmatrix} \\ \text{(normalized basis)}$$

The second matrix agrees with all of the formulas given on Wolfram Mathworld. It can be obtained by substituting $u^\theta\to u^\theta/r$ in the expression given in the holonomic basis and then multiplying through by the appropriate magnitudes of the basis elements.

Given below is a Mathematica script that will generate both of these matrices.

```
$Assumptions = (_ \[Element] Reals && 
   r > 0);   (*Tells Mathematica to assume all variables are real, and that the radius is positive*)
dim = 3;
q = {r, \[Theta], z};
p = {r Cos[\[Theta]], r Sin[\[Theta]], z};
e = Table[D[p, q[[i]]], {i, 1, dim}];
norme = Simplify[Table[Norm[e[[i]]], {i, 1, dim}]];
g = Simplify[
   Table[D[p, q[[i]]] . D[p, q[[j]]], {i, 1, dim}, {j, 1, dim}]];
inverseg = Simplify[Inverse[g]];
duale = Table[Sum[inverseg[[i, j]]*e[[j]], {i, 1, dim}], {j, 1, dim}];
normduale = Simplify[Table[Norm[duale[[j]]], {j, 1, dim}]];
\[CapitalGamma] = 
  Table[Sum[
    inverseg[[k, m]]/
     2 (D[g[[i, k]], q[[j]]] + D[g[[j, k]], q[[i]]] - 
       D[g[[i, j]], q[[k]]]), {k, 1, dim}], {m, 1, dim}, {i, 1, 
    dim}, {j, 1, dim}];
u = {ur[r, \[Theta], z], u\[Theta][r, \[Theta], z], 
   uz[r, \[Theta], z]};
uNORMALIZED = Table[1/norme[[i]]*u[[i]], {i, 1, dim}];
Delu = Table[(D[u[[i]], q[[j]]]) + 
   Sum[\[CapitalGamma][[i, j, k]] u[[k]], {k, 1, dim}], {i, 1, 
   dim}, {j, 1, dim}]
DeluNORMALIZED = 
 Table[norme[[i]]*
   normduale[[j]]*((D[uNORMALIZED[[i]], q[[j]]]) + 
     Sum[\[CapitalGamma][[i, j, k]] uNORMALIZED[[k]], {k, 1, 
       dim}]), {i, 1, dim}, {j, 1, dim}]
```

And here it is in action:

[image: output]

Comment: This is very, very helpful and greatly appreciated! Unfortunately, while I can follow your reasoning and calculation to determine the (1,2) component as you present, I am unable to use this procedure to calculate the (2,1) and (2,2) components. The (2,1) component seems to have a term that doesn't vanish because `\Gamma^\theta_{r\theta} = 1/r`, and the (2,2) component seems to yield an additional dependence on r. Based on your (**) equation, should the first term on the RHS of the equation just above "And hence" have `r` as a subscript? (I don't think this causes the problem). Thanks again!

Comment: @dpholmes No, it is the (1,2) component - why would it have an r subscript?

Comment: I'm referring to `1/||e^r||` vs. `1/||e_r||` based on the definition in (**)

Comment: I feel confident that it should be 1/||e_r||. If so, I calculate the (1,1), (1,2), and (2,2) components correctly. However, I suspect I'm calculating the Christoffel symbols for \Gamma^\theta_{r\theta} incorrectly, but I keep getting 1/r.

Comment: @dpholmes Yes, my mistake. It should be e^r and not e_r. But it makes no difference because their magnitude is both $1$ in this case.

Comment: @dpholmes Please have a look at my edits.

Comment: Thank you for your patience. I was making a simple mistake of forgetting to apply the product rule when calculating the (2,1) component, which is why I couldn't get rid of that pesky u^\theta/r term. Thanks for walking me through this - I am not sure I would have ever sorted out the fact that most of the differential geometry equations I'm used to are in terms of the holonomic basis, while most of the calculations I need expect an orthonormal basis. Thank you.

Comment: Coming back to this a while later - if this sufficiently answered your question be sure to accept the answer.

Comment: I would be happy to accept the answer, but since I did not ask the original question, it appears I cannot accept the answer. I have upvoted wherever possible!

Comment: @dpholmes my mistake

Answer (score 1):

The thing you forgot is the scale factor $\frac{1}{r}$ given in equation (14).  See Scale Factor in Mathworld.

Comment: I don't see how the scale factor is involved with the first term. Could you explain it a little more explicitly? My understanding of this is a little shaky...

Comment: Does this come from taking the components of $A$ with respect to the orthonormal basis instead of the holonomic basis?