# Divergence of a tensor in cylindrical coordinates

Tags: tensors, divergence-operator, cylindrical-coordinates

I'm having a hard time finding a source with an actual derivation on this. I understand the divergence of a vector field in cylindrical coordinates. However, for a tensor, how do I go from this

$$\nabla \cdot \mathbf{S} = \left( \hat{r} \frac{\partial}{\partial r} + \hat{\theta} \frac{1}{r} \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} + \hat{z} \frac{\partial}{\partial z}\right) \cdot \begin{pmatrix} S_{rr}  \:  \hat{r} \otimes \hat{r} + S_{r \theta}  \: \hat{r} \otimes \hat{\theta} + S_{rz}  \: \hat{r} \otimes \hat{z}\\
+ S_{\theta r}  \: \hat{\theta} \otimes \hat{r} + S_{\theta \theta} \: \hat{\theta} \otimes \hat{\theta} +  S_{\theta z} \: \hat{\theta} \otimes \hat{z}\\
+ S_{z r} \: \hat{z} \otimes \hat{r} +  S_{z \theta} \: \hat{z} \otimes \hat{\theta} +  S_{z z} \: \hat{z} \otimes \hat{z}\end{pmatrix}$$

to this

$$\nabla \cdot \mathbf{S} = \begin{bmatrix} \frac{\partial S_{rr}}{\partial r} + \frac{S_{rr}}{r} + \frac{1}{r} \frac{\partial S_{\theta r}}{\partial \theta} + \frac{\partial S_{zr}}{\partial z} - \frac{S_{\theta \theta}}{r} \\
\frac{1}{r} \frac{\partial S_{\theta \theta}}{\partial \theta} + \frac{\partial S_{r \theta}}{\partial r} + \frac{S_{r \theta}}{r} + \frac{S_{\theta r}}{r} + \frac{\partial S_{z \theta}}{\partial z}\\
\frac{\partial S_{z z}}{\partial z} + \frac{\partial S_{r z}}{\partial r} + \frac{S_{rz}}{r} + \frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial S_{\theta z}}{\partial \theta}\end{bmatrix}$$

?

I understand **why** the term $- \frac{S_{\theta \theta}}{r}$ appears (because the unit vectors are differentiated, which does not give zero), but I can not find the way to execute this calculation. I probably am missing some tensor algebra rules. How exactly is it done?

I care especially for the top row and the $- \frac{S_{\theta \theta}}{r}$ term. $\hat{r}$, $\hat{\theta}$ and $\hat{z}$ are supposed to be unit vectors, obviously.

Comment: Please use mathJax.

Comment: @KurtG. Now nicely formatted.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/833179/covariant-derivative-in-cylindrical-coordinates/4643576#4643576

Comment: @K.defaoite are there other ways to explain it? I am an engineer ...

Comment: Is what you're looking for the definition of dot product here? It ought to be $u\cdot(v\otimes w) = (u\cdot v)w$. The derivatives can be applied before hand with the product rule because the product rule applies to any bilinear product like $\otimes$. So for instance:

Comment: $$(\hat r\partial_r)\cdot(S_{r\theta}\hat r\otimes\hat\theta) = \hat r\cdot((\partial_r S_{r\theta})\hat r\otimes\hat\theta + S_{r\theta}(\partial_r\hat r)\otimes\hat\theta + S_{r\theta}\hat r\otimes(\partial_r\hat\theta)) = (\partial_r S_{r\theta})(\hat r\cdot\hat r)\hat\theta + S_{r\theta}(\hat r\cdot\partial_r\hat r)\hat\theta + S_{r\theta}(\hat r\cdot\hat r)\partial_r\hat\theta.$$

Comment: And in this case the second and third term drop out (derivative is zero) and in the first the unit vectors become $\left(\hat{r} \cdot \hat{r} \right) \hat{\theta} = 1\, \hat{\theta}$ therefore it ends up in the second row?

Comment: @Felix Yes, correct. This is precisely the second term you see in the second row.

Comment: @NicholasTodoroff You are a saint. I might seem like a simpleton to you now, but I find this amazing and it works! Can you please provide your comment as a normal answer so I can accept it? I am sure there will be more students who will find this question useful.

Comment: @NicholasTodoroff I'll wait a few more days and then answer the question myself, referring to your solution in the comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dot product, as best as I can guess, is meant to be a left tensor contraction so that
$$
  u\cdot(v\otimes w) = (u\cdot v)w.
$$
Because the tensor product is bilinear the product rule for the derivatives $\partial_r, \partial_\theta, \partial_z$ is valid (where I've used the abbreviated notation $\partial_a = \partial/\partial a$). So for instance we can compute
$$\begin{aligned}{}
  [(\hat\theta/r)\partial_\theta]\cdot[S_{\theta\theta}\hat\theta\otimes\hat\theta]
    &= \frac1r\hat\theta\cdot\Bigl[(\partial_\theta S_{\theta\theta})\hat\theta\otimes\hat\theta + S_{\theta\theta}(\partial_\theta\hat\theta)\otimes\hat\theta + S_{\theta\theta}\hat\theta\otimes(\partial_\theta\hat\theta)\Bigr]
\\
    &= \frac1r\Bigl[(\partial_\theta S_{\theta\theta})(\hat\theta\cdot\hat\theta)\hat\theta + 0 - S_{\theta\theta}(\hat\theta\cdot\hat\theta)\hat r\Bigr]
\\
    &= \frac{\partial_\theta S_{\theta\theta}}r\hat\theta - \frac{S_{\theta\theta}}r\hat r.
\end{aligned}$$
This is the origin of the particular term $-S_{\theta\theta}/r$.